# display data from database based on user login

Tags: php, mysql

I want admins to be able to approve members based on their user login. I have a memebers table having all their information. Suppose an admin `username= "Mary"` and `password="xxxx"` and `location="canada"`, then only members having their `location= "canada"` should be displayed. 
This is what I have done so far. Using this Sql query, `$view_members_query="select * from members";`  which displays all the members in the database. I need to display only what the admin should see based on location. Please assist me.

Thanks

Admin Login

```
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","table");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
  echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
  // checking the user
  session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['location']);
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
 $sel_user = "select * from Admin_table where location= '$location' AND   user_name='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($run_user)>0)
 {
 echo "<script>window.open('memberslist.php','_self')</script>"; 
 $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST['username'];
 }
else {
echo "<script>alert('Location, Username or password is not correct, try again!')  </script>";
 }}
 ?>
```

memberslist.php

```
 <table class="simple-table">  
    <thead>  
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>       
  <?php

    $view_members_query="select * from members"; 
    $run=mysqli_query($con,$view_members_query); 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and   store in a array $row.  
    {       
        $fname=$row[1];
        $lname=$row[2];             
         $location=$row[3];

    ?>  
    <tr>  
 <!--here showing results in the table --> 

        <td><?php echo $firstname;  ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $lastname;  ?></td>      
        <td><?php echo $location;  ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In your login code store the location of the user in the session the same way you store the username.

2) In the sql code in the memberlist.php use [where criteria](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) to filter based on the location. Actually, the code is already in the login page's code, since you use location to login a user. Just remember to use the location from the [session](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm).

Comment: I thought of the where condition but if i use where location=location, then how do I link it to the admin login? I don't really know how to use sessions. please explain how I can achieve this

Comment: You link to the admin account through the session. By saving the location to session at login and using this information when you query the members ensure that each admin will see the relevant members only. Updated the answer with a link to how to use sessions.